# How to calculate a -value for the difference between two non normal distributions of counts?

Tags: t-test, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have two NON normal distributions (a and b), they are also different lengths

```
> dim(a)
[1] 31385     2
> dim(b)
[1] 103   2
> head(a)
        gene_id          number_of_eqtles_per_gene
1 ENSG00000237683.5                         5
2 ENSG00000225972.1                       267
3 ENSG00000225630.1                        97

> head(b)
         gene_id           number_of_eqtles_per_gene
1  ENSG00000187608.5                       160
2  ENSG00000186891.9                       237
3 ENSG00000142632.12                       597
```

I want to compare number_of_eqtles_per_gene between a and b.
My question is does it make sense here to use Wilcoxon test to compute this p value via:

```
wilcox.test(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene, y = b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene,paired = FALSE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene and b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene
W = 1371200, p-value = 0.007768
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

If I do log transform and t.test this is what I get:

```
al=log(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene)
bl=log(b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene)
t.test(al,bl,paired = FALSE)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  al and bl
  t = -2.8189, df = 102.91, p-value = 0.00578
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.7228042 -0.1257740
 sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 4.428042  4.852332
```

Please let me know what would be correct way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT1

Per @FransRodenburg suggestion bellow I did this:

```
DF <- data.frame(a_or_b = c(rep("a", nrow(a)), rep("b", nrow(b))), number_of_eqtles_per_gene = c(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene, b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene))
GLM2 <- glm.nb(number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b, data = DF)
summary(GLM2)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b, data = DF, 
init.theta = 0.5856471626, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2316  -1.2039  -0.4624   0.1993   6.7996  

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 5.493198   0.007385 743.844   <2e-16 ***
a_or_bb     0.070094   0.129111   0.543    0.587    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.5856) family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 38562  on 31487  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 38562  on 31486  degrees of freedom
AIC: 401897

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  0.58565 
      Std. Err.:  0.00397 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -401891.13900
```

EDIT2

To test for independency between "a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene" and "b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene" I did:

Since lengths of "b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene" and "a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene" are deifferent I used this transformation:

```
max.len = max(length(b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene),     length(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene))
x = c(b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene, rep(NA, max.len - length(b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene)))
y = c(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene, rep(NA, max.len - length(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene)))
tbl = table(x, y)
#performed Pearson's Chi-squared test
chisq.test(x,y)

data:  x and y
X-squared = 8094.1, df = 8008, p-value = 0.2473

Warning message:
In chisq.test(x, y) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

EDIT3

If I am to use Poisson via:

```
DF <- data.frame(a_or_b = c(rep("a", nrow(a)), rep("b", nrow(b))), number_of_eqtles_per_gene = c(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene, b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene))
GLM2 <- glm(number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b, data = DF,family=poisson(link="log"))
summary(GLM2)
coef(summary(GLM2))[,4]
exp(confint(GLM2))

Call:
glm(formula = number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b, family = poisson(link = "log"), 
data = DF)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-22.313  -17.454   -8.434    4.240  246.204  

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 5.4929500  0.0003627 15143.69   <2e-16 ***
a_or_bb     0.0703421  0.0061136    11.51   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 11557163  on 31384  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 11557033  on 31383  degrees of freedom
AIC: 11754074

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

> coef(summary(GLM2))[,4]
 (Intercept)      a_or_bb 
0.000000e+00 1.231544e-30 
> exp(confint(GLM2))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
             2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 242.800230 243.145699
a_or_bb       1.060071   1.085782
```

If I do just a standard t.test:

```
ax=a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene
bx=b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene
t.test(ax,bx,paired = FALSE)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  ax and bx
t = -0.70549, df = 103.92, p-value = 0.4821
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -67.47791  32.06454
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 242.9729  260.6796
```

Can someone please help me interpret these results?

Comment: Welcome to the site. The Wilcoxon rank sum test makes no assumption of normality, so of course it is fine to use it here. The question however, is: What are you trying to demonstrate? It is unclear from the question what you're trying to do, but the first thing that comes to mind when seeing `number_of_...` is the use a model for *counts*, rather than a non-parametric test.

Comment: I also suggest editing the title. A $p$-value is a chance of observing a test statistic at least as large as the one observed if the null-hypothesis were true. There is are no $p$-values for probability distributions outside the context of a significance test. Something like: "How to calculate a $p$-value for the *difference between*..." would be more correct.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! Yes I am trying to compare counts in two distributions. I understand Wilcoxon is hard to interpret. Is there is any other method you would suggest for this particular case?

Comment: Are these counts indpendent? A lot of the mentioned models in the form they are proposed (e.g. Wilcoxon rank test, Poisson, NegBin) assume independent (as opposed to correlated) observations. E.g. for counts of something from different people this might be reasonable, e.g. for gene expression on neighboring genes that is typically not true. Before directly jumping to picking a model, one should also think about what is independent or not in the data

Comment: Hi Bjorn, I did Pearson's Chi-squared test, please see the EDIT2 in my post and please let me know what you think.

Comment: What Björn meant is dependence between measurements, this is not something you can simply test for, you should include some information on how you collected the data (what do they represent exactly?), if dependence is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

A general way to compare counts is in the context of a [generalized linear model (GLM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model). Specifically, you could use a Poisson, or negative binomial GLM of the form:

```
GLM1 <- glm(number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b, family = "poisson") # Poisson
GLM2 <- glm.nb(number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b) # negative binomial
```

Since you have plenty of observations, I recommend the latter, since it estimates an extra dispersion parameter, to account for potential overdispersion.

You can then produce a summary to see if there is a significant effect of `a_or_b`, which represents the effect of being from `a`, or from `b` in my example:

```
summary(GLM2)
```

A GLM uses a link function, which by default is the logarithm for Poisson and NB models, so the difference you will see is on the log-scale.

There are many questions on this site about GLMs. If you include your data, I might update this answer to include an interpretation of the results.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for explaining me, still I am afraid I don't understand how to apply what you suggested for my data frames. In my data frames (a and b) I have two columns: gene_id and number_of_eqtles_per_gene, Can you please send me how the command for GLM2  would exactly look like?

Comment: That depends what exactly you want to compare. If not the number of eQTLs(?) between `a` and `b`, could you edit your question to include what it is?

Comment: I want to compare number_of_eqtles_per_gene between a and b

Comment: `DF <- data.frame(a_or_b = c(rep("a", nrow(a)), rep("b", nrow(b))), number_of_eqtles_per_gene = c(a$number_of_eqtles_per_gene, b$number_of_eqtles_per_gene)); GLM2 <- glm.nb(number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b, data = DF); summary(GLM2)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I posted your code and the output. And the p value seem to be 0.5872002. So not significant I suppose?

Comment: Hi Frans, I was wondering would it be better to do have  Poisson regression, like this: GLM3 <- glm(number_of_eqtles_per_gene ~ a_or_b, data = DF,family=poisson(link="log"))? One distribution is small I think, 103, and the other one much bigger 31385. What is the way to include my data here? I'm sorry for asking this very basic questions

Comment: I included in my post also Poisson analysis and standard t.test for comparison. Can you please help me interpret these results?

Comment: @anamaria `GLM3` would be identical to `GLM1`, because that is the default link function. I recommend using version `GLM2`. The result would then not be significant. The difference in group size does not matter that much. The `t.test` is not necessary for comparison, but agrees with the NB model that the there is no significant difference.